# What group is the Galois group $G(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Recently in my abstract algebra II course we have been studying Galois theory. I have been doing a lot of reading and came across the Galois group $G(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ (The set of all automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ that fix $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise) and naturally being an abstract algebra student I immediately asked the question:

To what group is $G(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to?

I believe $G(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ has two elements: the complex conjugation automorphism and the identity automorphism. Would it maybe be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}$? I can’t find any suppporting evidence of this in my book so if there are any relevant theorems that could supplement my question, please feel free to add.

Comment: What’s the degree of that extension?

Comment: The degree is 2, right? Since $\mathbb{C}$ $=$ $\mathbb{R}$(i)

Comment: Yes exactly! And how do degree and the size of the Galois group relate for Galois extensions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without deep machinery, any field automorphism $\phi$ of $\Bbb C$ that leaves $\Bbb R$ pointwise fix is determined by $\phi(i)$ as we must have $\phi(x+iy)=x+\phi(i)y$. Also $$0=\phi(0)=\phi(1+i^2)=1+\phi(i)^2$$ implies that $\phi(i)\in\{i,-i\}$. Hence indeed there are exactly two such automorphisms: the identity and complex conjugation. So $G(\Bbb C/\Bbb R)$ is *the* group of order $2$.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. So would it be correct to say that this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}$ ? Or is there another group that we can think of?

Comment: That's very nice!

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in the comments, $\mathbb C = \mathbb R(i)$ makes it a degree 2 extension. It is normal but the fundamental theorem of algebra and separable because the characteristic is 0, hence Galois. So the size of the Galois group is the degree, and clearly complex conjugation works as the nonzero element generating that Galois group.

Comment: One does not need the fundamental theorem of algebra, if you note $\mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{R}[X]/(x^2+1)$

Comment: You're right, just being degree 2 guarantees normality. I was trying to be lazy but just ended up being silly :)

Answer (score 1):

It is $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}(i) $ with $ [\mathbb{C}: \mathbb{R}] = 2 $ since the minimal polynomial of $ i $ is $ X^2+1$. So the extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is a galois extension with galois group of order 2. Hence it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What theorem is this coming from?

Comment: One can easily show that a group with a prime order is cyclic. There is a Theorem classifying the cyclic groups. Namely: If G is a cyclic group, then it is isomorphic to Z/mZ if the order of G is m or G is isomorphic to Z if G is of infinite order.